# How to achieve this layout in Interface Builder?

Tags: ios, swift, user-interface, interface-builder

I'm using a static Table View Controller and defining the UI in Interface Builder.

I want all of the UILabels to be the same width so that the the left side of the UITextFields line up.

If I force a width, then they often overdraw each other.

[image]

I was thinking of modifying the UILabel width programmatically, based on the width of "Safe Message" within the controller, but I couldn't get it to re-layout.

```
let width = labelSafeMessage.frame.size.width;
labelName.frame.size.width = labelSafeMessage.frame.size.width;
labelName.sizeToFit();
labelMessage.frame.size.width = labelSafeMessage.frame.size.width;
labelMessage.sizeToFit();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this using only Interface Build and you do not need to force labels to have the same size.The only thing that you need to do is set leading spacing of UITextFields to superview and they will be aligned to left side.

Answer (score 0):

you could avoid re-layout by calculating the width before the tableView displays data.

get the largest string in the set, and then use this

```
var str = "Hello, playground"
let constraintRect = CGSize(width: CGFloat.greatestFiniteMagnitude, height: DEFINED_HEIGHT)
let boundingBox = (str as? NSString)?.boundingRect(with: constraintRect, options: NSStringDrawingOptions.usesLineFragmentOrigin, attributes: [NSFontAttributeName: FONT], context: nil)
boundingBox.width //width for the labels
```

Just replace the DEFINED_HEIGHT with the height for the label which would be the height of the row minus the top and bottom constraints that hold it.
and the FONT, for the font used in the label.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using a `UITableView` you could use a vertical `UIStackView` who will contains `UIViews`.

Set your `UILabels` constraints to `Align Leading edges` and `Align Trailing edges` and set the `Content Hugging Priority` and `Content Compression Resistance Priority` as well as the label don't be cropped and fit correctly.

Set the `UITextFields` constraints to `Align Leading edges` and `Align Trailing edges` to each other and that will do the trick.